# Remove padding from sides (left, right)

Tags: html, css

Hi yes I been developing some css for a project I've been working on but I can't seem to remove the padding from both sides of the websites.

I am not sure where the problem is so I'll just give you my whole css code

CSS Help!!!

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I don't think anyone's going to want to go through thousands of lines of CSS to try to find the issue. You might be able to use the Inspector in the Firefox or Chrome dev tools to figure out which rules are adding the padding.

Comment: Well actually real people that have experience with coding and CSS wouldn't have a problem with looking through my code considering they've probably done the same before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add below style in your css:

```
section .inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  width: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
section .inner {
    /* max-width: 65em; */
    /* width: calc(100% - 6em); */
}
```

the code above is causing the spacing on the left and right, comment that out and see if thats what you require.

its in index and main css..